# Convert string to list in python

Tags: python

I need to convert an string to a list in python,
The string format is as follows,

```
'[{"name":"Tom","adress":"adress1"},{"name":"Mari","adress":"adress2"}]'
```

I need to convert this **string** in to python **list** data type and want to get the dictionaries by iterating that generated list.

I have tried json library and no luck. > correction (**json.loads is working**.)

Can you please tell me the correct way to do so ?

Comment: The `json` library loads your example just fine. What was the problem you encountered?

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: So if using `json` worked, what was the actual problem? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `ast.literal_eval` it without any problem.

```
>>> s = '[{"name":"Tom","adress":"adress1"},{"name":"Mari","adress":"adress2"}]'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[{'adress': 'adress1', 'name': 'Tom'}, {'adress': 'adress2', 'name': 'Mari'}]
```

but `json.loads` doesn't seem to have any problem with it either ...

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
[{u'adress': u'adress1', u'name': u'Tom'}, {u'adress': u'adress2', u'name': u'Mari'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Yes both are working. I will edit my post

Comment: An alternative is to use `eval()`, though it is unsafe.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky -- Why suggest `eval` when there's a safe alternative for this problem in the standard library?

Answer (score 3):

As was noted in several comments, the `eval` builtin function is capable of parsing such strings but is not secure! So the `ast.literal_eval` method should be preferred.

Comment: If `ast.literal_eval` can handle it, certainly `eval` can.  But why use `eval` when `ast.literal_eval` will suffice?

Comment: The good old `eval` can also easily lead to serious security vulnerabilities.